# MonoTouch CopyCurrentNetworkInfo Incorrect

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, ssid, captivenetwork

I am using the following code to get the current SSID:

```
var dict = CaptiveNetwork.CopyCurrentNetworkInfo(curInterface);
string localSsid = dict [CaptiveNetwork.NetworkInfoKeySSID].ToString();
Console.Writeline("Current Local SSID: " + localSsid);
```

However, often the result is out of date (on the order of minutes or more).  I noticed that if I go into settings on the iPad and manually switch to another network just for 5 seconds and then switch back, that the code will then capture the correct SSID.

I am running iOS 5.0 and MonoTouch 3.2.12. Is my code incorrect or is this a bug in MonoTouch or iOS?

Answer (score 0):

`MonoTouch.SystemConfiguration.CaptiveNetwork.CopyCurrentNetworkInfo` is a direct p/invoke to Apple's [`CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/CaptiveNetworkRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo).

IOW there's no caching of the data being done by MonoTouch but, from your description, I assume iOS is doing some by itself. Not sure it would be considered a bug or not but I encourage you to fill a [bug report](https://bugreport.apple.com/) with Apple.

> Monotouch 3.2.12

That's likely 5.2.12 :-)